Cipher seen while walking

I was walking and saw this cipher does any one know how to crack it?

Welcome to PSE!

Can you add some background information about where you saw this? It might give some clues/context that will help solve it.

It looks like some sort of phonetic transcription or shorthand to me. If so, it is a rhyming couplet seemingly followed by the phrase "What am I?" per the bottom line

very partial answer:

 it seems that the ° particle encodes the "a" sound in a syllable, as it's the only element present in all of the rosetta's syllables.


 the rest of the rosetta is then seemingly obvious


 this enables us to find that the r symbol just above the "at" of the rosetta encodes an "L" sound, because there are not very many english words that start with "wa" and end in "a". In fact, all i could find was "wallah" (and it's variants), indicating that this symbol encodes this sound. However, given that this supposed "wallah" is surrounded by the same word on both sides, i'll concede that my conclusion is probably wrong.

